# This UWP process is suspended to improve system performance ... but it isn't a UWP app

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-10, suspend

We have a WPF app build on .NET Framework 4.8, but recently we saw this in the taskbar (running on windows 10 x64) :

[image: Taskbar]

When hovering over the WPF client, the tooltip said 'This UWP process is suspended to improve system performance'. Our app was also hanging for a while before doing some work again. How is this possible? We're not running on .NET Core 3.0, no desktop bridge, no UWP integration at all ... it's just a normal WPF app.

Comment: I checked internally and this appears to just be a bug in Task Manager. Do you know what the cause of the hang was?

Comment: Thanks for checking. We fixed a lot of performance issues over the last bit, the hang was seen at some point, but is probably fixed at  this point. I had to look into that tooltip if I could determine why we saw that. :-)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I've noticed similar behaviour - a green leaf icon appeared for non-UWP process in Task Manager. I wonder if this bug is registered somewhere in the list of known issues for Windows 10?